# Trying to get data(text) from parse.com and then give to base adapter and then set this adapter to listview

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform, baseadapter

In detail problem is I am Using parse.com as backend and I am trying to get text data into my app i have created class on parse.com and in my app also.
this is my class code from app to get data from parse:

```
@ParseClassName("WhatsApp")
public class WhatsApp extends ParseObject {
    public String gettitle(){
        return getString("title");
    }
    public void settitle(String title){
        put("title",title);
    }
    public String getdes(){
        return getString("des");
    }
    public void setdes(String des){
        put("des",des);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getString("title")+"\n"+(getString("des"));
    }
}
```

now how i can get 1 column data from parse **only**  title  with the help of this class and create a base adapter to design row .can anyone give me example how this can done thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the fields returned by using selectKeys method in ParseQuery.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("WhatsApp");
query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("title"));;
List<ParseObject> results = query.find();
```

The remaining fields can be fetched later by calling one of the fetchIfNeeded variants on the returned objects:

```
ParseObject object = results.get(0);
object.fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    // all fields of the object will now be available here.
  }
});
```